# How to use UWPCommunityToolkit BladeView in a web app?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Newbie to web dev and windows stack. I'm keen to use UWPCommunityToolkit's [BladeView](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/BladeView/) but for a web application and not for a windows app.
How can I leverage the BladeView [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/BladeView) and import such a UI framework inside a web app?

Comment: Since Silverlight is being outphased, there's no XAML for web. You'll have to look for html/css/js variants on the web.

Comment: If I am not wrong, while Silverlight is dead, using XAML for web apps does not seem to be anywhere close to death as is seen from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-xaml-browser-applications-overview. I could be mistaken though. Please correct me if I am missing anything here.